# Directx 12 : Sharing graphic memory between two processes

Tags: c++, directx-12

I am trying to create two applications. One application will render a texture off-screen and the second application will read it from graphic memory and render/present it on window.

My doubt is is it possible to share graphic memory in directx 12.

My named shared memory approach is causing comptr addref error...

I am using a comptr for `ID3D12Resource` for texture data...

So how can we go on with such approach...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly possible to render to offscreen texture and display it in another process. To display, you can call `CopyResource` or `CopyTextureRegion` to copy shared resource into the `Swapchain`'s backbuffer and then present it.

I'm not sure what you mean by your `named shared memory approach`, but to get interprocess memory sharing working you have to:

In process A:

- create resource within **shared** heap, e.g. via [ID3D12Device::CreateCommittedResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-createcommittedresource)
- call [ID3D12Device::CreateSharedHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-createsharedhandle) on the resource

In process B:

- call [ID3D12Device::OpenSharedHandleByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-opensharedhandlebyname) to obtain shared handle (called NT handle)
- call [ID3D12Device::OpenSharedHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-opensharedhandle) to create resource from the handle

Sample sketched quickly (creates a buffer, but that shouldn't be any different for textures):

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> ptr{};
if (isProcessA) {
    HANDLE handle{};
    throwIfFailed(device->CreateCommittedResource(
        &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES{D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT},
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_SHARED,
        &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(1024),
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON,
        nullptr,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&ptr)));
    throwIfFailed(device->CreateSharedHandle(ptr.Get(), nullptr, GENERIC_ALL, L"Name", &handle));
} else {
    HANDLE handle{};
    throwIfFailed(device->OpenSharedHandleByName(L"Name", GENERIC_ALL, &handle));
    throwIfFailed(device->OpenSharedHandle(handle, IID_PPV_ARGS(&ptr)));
}
```

Note, that you have to avoid collisions of `Name` values passed to the [ID3D12Device::CreateCommittedResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12device-createcommittedresource).

For further reference, see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/shared-heaps).

Comment: yes u r spot on... although i found the respective MSDN documentation for it btw...THANKS...